# Term to a verse that starts with the last word of the previous verse

Tags: terminology, poetry, music

The music "Glad you came" by The Wanted has the following verses

> Turn the lights out now, now I'll take you by the hand
>
> Hand you another drink, drink it if you can
>
> Can you spend a little time, time is slipping away
>
> Away from us so stay, stay with me I can make
>
> Make you glad you came

Is there a term for it?

Comment: See also  [What type of wordplay joins two phrases together on a single syllable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/348728/26083)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anadiplosis: [repetition of the final words of a sentence or line at the beginning of the next](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/5189/anadiplosis)

[Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis#Examples)

Answer (score 5):

It's a form of chain verse, or a chain rhyme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rhyme