# What type of wordplay joins two phrases together on a single syllable?

Tags: word-usage, jokes, humor

During a South Park episode, Wendy sings a song with a specific type of wordplay in which she ends a sentence and starts a new one with a common word or syllable. This gives the lyrics a double meaning each time. This isn't the only example of this but it's the most easy one to find an example for.

A lame, tame example of the pattern is:

> There are 12 inches in a foot ball is my favorite sport.

I wondered if there was a specific name for this? 
"Double Entendre" doesn't really do it justice.

You can see and hear the song [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vsNfZ3jsE). 
Warning: the language is strongly suggestive and is probably NSFW. 
The lyrics listed on the YouTube page are:

> Mrs. Landers was a health nut, she cooked food in a wok.
> Mr. Harris was her boyfriend, and he had a great big—
> COCK-a-doodle-doodle. The rooster just won't quit.
> I don't want my breakfast, because it tastes like—
> SHITzus make good pets, they're cuddly and sweet.
> Monkeys aren't good to have 'cause they like beat their—
> MEETing in the office, meeting in the hall.
> The boss, he wants to see you, so you can suck his—
> BALZac was a writer, he lived with Alan Funt.
> Mrs. Roberts didn't like him, but that's 'cause she's a—
> CONTaminated water, can really make you sick.
> Your bladder gets infected, and blood comes out your—
> DICtate what I'm saying, 'cause it'll bring you luck.
> And if you all don't like it, I don't give a flying F**K!

Comment: Questions regarding [lyrics and poetry](http://tinyurl.com/hxpj3hq) are considered off-topic for this website, because they often fail to conform to the rules of prose. We also have research standards: If a known word or phrase doesn't work for you, consult [a thesaurus](http://tinyurl.com/z4br8dq) and tell us why it's inadequate. Please read the topics about how to ask questions in our [help center topics](http://tinyurl.com/jlol7sj) for more information. If this can be phrased in the form of a [S.W.R.](http://tinyurl.com/87c5y3m), please edit the question with a hypothetical usage sentence.

Comment: Can you include the lyrics in your question?

Comment: "Big Ten Inch Record" and the "Shaving Cream Song" use vaguely similar techniques; try researching those.

Comment: also “Polka Dot Undies” (1986).

Comment: @Tonepoet Questions about lyrics and poetry are not off-topic for this website, something your link clearly indicates, so I don't know where you got that idea. Questions involving cultural significance or literary analysis are off-topic for lyrics and poetry, but those kind of questions would be off-topic for prose as well.  The OP asks about a term for double meanings based on elided syllables in contiguous phrases. I don't know whether there is one (or how a thesaurus would help find one), but it's certainly a reasonable question.

Comment: @deadrat Not inherently. My original draft said "often" but I couldn't fit everything, even after shortening the links, so I had to drop it. Trust me when [I say myself and others have seen poetry topics closed for a variety of reasons](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/267245/124936), including ambiguous metaphors, nonstandard syntax, nonstandard pronunciation ect. Also, you can see why I mentioned [S.W.Rs. in Lawrence's Sandy Lines chat-room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32328491#32328491) If you don't mind,  I'd like you to review some subjects we've been discussing.

Comment: @Tonepoet I don't need to trust you: in my comment I acknowledge that there are close-worthy reasons. My objection is to classifying as off-topic a request for rhetorical term simply because the example is song lyrics. If you want me to review topics in the chat-room, please save me the eye strain and tell me what they are.

Comment: @AntonSherwood "Polka Dot Undies" is the same type of wordplay as the classic ["Sweet Violets"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtnLvrmyh3E). "Wendy's Cussing Song" is a bit different.

Comment: See also  [Term for a verse that starts with the last word of the previous verse](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/165407/26083).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your example involves ***enjambment***, ***homophones***, and ***mind rhyme***.

***[Enjambment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enjambment)*** is the running together of lines. In a normal case of enjambment, a complete clause is separated over two lines, as in this couplet from Auden:

> Keep running if you want to reach
>   the point of knowing where you stand.

But with your example of

> I don't want my breakfast, because it tastes like—
>   Shih Tzus make good housepets, they're cuddly and sweet,
>   Monkeys aren't good to have, because they like to beat their—
>   Meeting in the office...

each line is interrupted and a new one began. But the initial sounds of the subsequent lines can be viewed as completing the previous lines. This is because these initial sounds are homophones for what you'd expect the previous line to end with. ***[Homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)*** are words that are pronounced the same but differ in meaning (for example *meet* and *meat*). The homophonic material starting the subsequent line can thus be viewed as the enjambed completion of the previous line.

As the lines are interrupted, their *actual* completions are only suggested. The device of suggesting a rhyme without actually giving it is called ***[mind rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_rhyme)***.

In fact, your specific example is mentioned in the Wikipedia article for mind rhyme (which also mentions an earlier example, ***[Miss Susie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Susie)***).

Mind rhyme that involves sexual innuendo or obscene language is sometimes called ***teasing rhyme***, although this term is also sometimes used more broadly to mean any mind rhyme.

Very generally, the song employs many puns, where a ***[pun](https://www.google.com/#q=define%20pun)*** is "a joke exploiting the... the fact that there are words that sound alike but have different meanings."

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Applauds "enjambment", what a great word.

Comment: One tiny footnote to this very good answer—in the television game show *Jeopardy* (and also apparently *Wheel of Fortune*), there is a category of answers involving this kind of phrase mash-up called "Before and After": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paaQJRgdSCk; in looking this up, I also ran across a language blogger who calls these POPs, for Phrasal Overlap Portmanteau: https://arnoldzwicky.org/2010/05/13/phrasal-overlap-portmanteaus/